# what happens behind the scenes of executing `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I'm wondering what's happening behind the scenes when registering ios applications for push notifications and how the ios device receives device-token in `application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` callback. I need to know the complete scenario and protocol communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most related things I could find are:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

what I could understand is that most of the work is done by os that establishes a direct and persistent connection to apple's servers. no more information about any protocols or request-responses.

Answer (score 0):

So this all works like this:

1) Your app asks to be registered with APNs.

2) On successful registration, APNs sends an app-specific device token to the device.

3) The system delivers the device to your app by calling a method in your app delegate.

For more information, check these links :-
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html

https://nshipster.com/apns-device-tokens/

Comment: what I need and want to know is the exact API calls being used (if any) and the protocol request-response steps from `registerForRemoteNotifications()` till receiving device-token.

Comment: I think there is no such exact explanation about this like api's call but I do know is UIKit calls this method after it successfully registers your app with APNs. In your implementation of this method, send the contents of the deviceToken parameter to the server that you use to generate remote notifications

Comment: the problem is some times when the phone is connected through wife, I neither get the call back for device token nor the failure callback. with cellular everything seems to work.

Comment: The ports apple uses are listed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609).    Your firewall must allow a direct, unproxied connections to 17.0.0.0/8 on these ports for push notifications to work.